# Python Image Library: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute XXX

Tags: python-imaging-library

I opened a picture with PIL, but when I tried to use `split()` to split the channels I got following error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bands'`

```
import Image
img = Image.open('IMG_0007.jpg')

img.split()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/blum/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in split(self)
   1495         "Split image into bands"
   1496 
-> 1497         if self.im.bands == 1:
   1498             ims = [self.copy()]
   1499         else:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bands'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With googling I found this [comment on SO, stating that PIL is sometimes 'lazy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228829/python-image-library-make-area-of-image-transparent#comment16387831_12229109)  and 'forgets' to load after opening. So you have to do it like this:

```
import Image
img = Image.open('IMG_0007.jpg')
img.load()
img.split()
```

**Please +1 also the original comment! This person did the real work.**

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that PIL was not installed correctly. When trying to read a png I'd get that error. My compilation summary yielded

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      linux2 2.7.3 (default, Apr 21 2012, 01:05:55)
              [GCC 4.6.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
*** TKINTER support not available
*** JPEG support not available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available <===============
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I then opted to "pip uninstall pil" and used the Synaptic Package Manager instead. That fixed it.