# Python Pillow: Applying multiple filters & enhancements to one image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I'd like to apply some filters to an uploaded image. The filters get generated based on a text that gets entered by the user. This is how the function looks so far:

```
    def validate_email(self):
    textboxValue = self.lineEdit.text()
    image = self.open()
    for c in textboxValue:
        if c == 'a':
            image = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(1.05)).show()
        elif c == 'b':
            image = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image)
            image.enhance(1.1).show()
        elif c == 'c':
            image = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
            image = image.enhance(1.1).show()
        elif c == '@':
            image = ImageOps.grayscale(image).show()
        else:
            print(c)
```

I'm pretty sure that yesterday my code worked, but today I constantly get the error

> AttributeError: object has no attribute ...

and the "..." differ, sometimes it's *enhance*, sometimes *getbands* etc.
It's always the **ImageEnhance** part that causes the error. The *GaussianBlur* filter is working fine..
I read about [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12413650/8411754) solution, but that didn't help me. I assume it's too old..

I'm new to Python so maybe I did some basic mistakes. I would be glad if somebody could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Image.show()` method does not return an image.

Actually the gaussian blur filter has the same problem, but it starts with a fresh image.

Just separate the show method call and it should be fine.

```
def validate_email(self):
    textboxValue = self.lineEdit.text()
    image = self.open()
    for c in textboxValue:
        if c == 'a':
            image = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(1.05))
            image.show()
        elif c == 'b':
            e = ImageEnhance.Brightness(image)
            image = e.enhance(1.1)
            image.show()
        elif c == 'c':
            e = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
            image = e.enhance(1.1)
            image.show()
        elif c == '@':
            image = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
            image.show()
        else:
            print(c)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just got rid of the image.show() statement!