# how to use function with parameters in python

Tags: python, image-processing

i am trying to scramble an image using pillow, i have my code but the keep getting this Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matthew.vandamboy\PycharmProjects\KatePixelation\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 166, in load
    seek = self.load_seek
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matthew.vandamboy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/matthew.vandamboy/PycharmProjects/KatePixelation/imageManipulation.py", line 10, in <lambda>
    self.buttonscram = tk.Button(master, text="Scramble", command= lambda : self.scrambledeggs(self.width , self.height, self.file ))
  File "C:/Users/matthew.vandamboy/PycharmProjects/KatePixelation/imageManipulation.py", line 25, in scrambledeggs
    setsized = self.img.resize((width , height))
  File "C:\Users\matthew.vandamboy\PycharmProjects\KatePixelation\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1876, in resize
    return self.copy()
  File "C:\Users\matthew.vandamboy\PycharmProjects\KatePixelation\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1112, in copy
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\matthew.vandamboy\PycharmProjects\KatePixelation\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 169, in load
    seek = self.fp.seek
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Here's my code; how would I stop this from happening?

```
from PIL import Image,ImageStat
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
import easygui

class gui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.buttonchoose = tk.Button(master, text="Choose image", command= self.fetchimage)
        self.buttonscram = tk.Button(master, text="Scramble", command= lambda : self.scrambledeggs(self.width , self.height, self.file ))
        self.buttonscram.pack()
        self.buttonchoose.pack()

    def fetchimage(self):
        file = easygui.fileopenbox()
        with Image.open(file) as self.img:
            self.width, self.height = self.img.size
        self.file  = file

        print(self.width , self.height)
        return file

    def scrambledeggs(self , width , height, file):

        setsized = self.img.resize((width , height))
        thechanger = np.array(setsized)

        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                for p in range(3):

                    if thechanger[i][j][p] % 2 == 0:
                        thechanger[i][j][p] = 255

        final = Image.fromarray(im, 'RGB')
        final.show()
```

Comment: The solution is a web search away: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413649/python-image-library-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-xxx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Image Library: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute XXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413649/python-image-library-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-xxx)