# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items' PIL exif

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I'm trying to get all image metadata using PIL Exif.There is a great snippet kinda has to work well but

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_exif(fn):
    ret = {}
    i = Image.open(fn)
    i.load()
    info = i._getexif()
    print(info)
    for tag, value in info.items():
        decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        ret[decoded] = value
    return ret

get_exif(img_path)
```

error without **i.load()**

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'

Image exists, "**i**" variable shows image. I tried different images but the same output happens. Firstly, I found here [Python Image Library - Make area of image transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228829/python-image-library-make-area-of-image-transparent#comment16387831_12229109) that error can be related to the fact that Image.open is lazy, so I added Image.load(). But it didn't help. May someone explain behaviour of the error and what should I try else to get the dictionary object of all image metadata?